# After altering form I cannot save changes in nodes

Tags: 7, forms

In drupal 7:
I have **Answer** content type and alter the form for that type:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'answer_node_form') {
    // disabling some fields (ie. #access title field to false)
    // setting defaults values
    // adding one hidden field (that shouldn't be inserted into database)
  }
}
```

A when I'm trying to submit edit form, the process of PHP takes too much time and Apache restarts.
Do you have any idea what is wrong? Maybe when I send the form, it shouldn't have any additional fields?

I could paste the code but I think it's insignificant.

Comment: I think you cannot simply remove the title. Try setting some default values using form_alter

Comment: Oh, I just hiding the title `$form['title']['#access'] = false;` so it is still sending via POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NikhilMohan says, you can't just remove fields like the title; they're required for validation. Event setting `#access => FALSE` has strange results in my experience.

What you could do instead, is set a value for the fields you're hiding, and change their `#type` to `'value'`. That way the element will still exist on the server side, and validation/submission won't break.

e.g.

```
$form['title']['#type'] = 'value';
$form['title']['#value'] = 'Some default value for the title';
```

Comment: OK, thanks for advice! I've implemented your solution, it is better, but my problem still exists.

Comment: OK, I've just figured it out that I should set #type to value in another field. And it helped.